# samba write only share from windows

Tags: file-permissions, samba, windows-share

I have a samba share which I want to write too but not be able to read.

```
[writeonly]
path = /writeonly
read only = no
create mask = 0772
guest ok = yes
guest account = gpcw
hide unreadable = yes
public = yes
browsable = no
writeable = yes
force user = gpcw
```

The permissions on the folder (owned by root) are 0772 which I understand to mean rwx for root:root and -w- for any other user.

I can mount the share from a windows server using `net use v: \\server\writeonly` but when I try to write I get permission denied.

If I change the unix permission to 0776 or 0777 I can write to the folder, but it unfortunately becomes readable.

My question is this, am I looking at a quirk of how windows maps samba folders in that it requires a read before it can write or is there something more significant likely to be happening?

Comment: I don't believe that write-only file systems make sense, regardless of whether it's in Samba or not. If you want to write to a file in such a file system, how would you figure out the directory details, location of the appropriate disk blocks, etc. without being able to read from the file system?

Comment: Think of it as your email's inbox: people can send emails, but once it's sent they lose control over it. They don't need to know what label/folder that email is going to be in, the email provider will take care of the exact location of that _dropped_ email. They leave it there and they are done. --- Also OS X has a special ["Drop Box" read-only public folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10640) that works fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it by sharing the folder normally (to the `Guest` user) and then simply changing the folder's permissions to allow `write` and deny `read` to `Guest`, like so:

[image: Write-only shared folder permissions]

In my case it can also be accessed from OS X, where the Windows' shared folder is mounted but it looks empty/unopenable. This message pops up when copy files to it: [image: You can put items into “Aggiunta Musica”, but you won’t be able to see them. Do you want to continue? Other users with sufficient permissions will be able to use the items.]

If you need to share it from an OS other than Windows, look for [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) in your OS.